# Checkbox does not style in mac chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to a style a checkbox in bootstrap. Which includes increasing height and width and changing the border. But with hard luck I found that
the only way was  using -webkit. Here is the code

```css
input.largerCheckbox {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" name="checkBox">
```

***In the above snippet, even the scale is zooming the checkbox the bigger size I wanted. It is simply distorted or out of shape.***
Is there any better way, Also border does not work. Any suggestions?

Note: I meant out of shape in mobile phones like iPhone or Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic way to style a checkbox is:

1- Wrap your checkbox in a label element.

2 -Hide your checkbox

3 - Add a new element after the checkbox which you will style accordingly.

I have create a fiddle with an example of checkbox with height and width larger than default.
https://jsfiddle.net/vz3pgsbq/1/

You can define the state unselected with this code:

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label::before, [type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    content: "";
    height: 28px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    width: 28px;
}
```

and the checked state:

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label::after, [type="checkbox"]:checked +     label::after {
    color: #09ad7e;
    content: "✔";
    font-size: 32px;
    left: 4px;
    line-height: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

More examples and tools for generate your checkbox can be find in this question:

[How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have to hide the default style and define your own. I don't know what size you want but this should do it. Just change the size to your needs.

```css
input.checkbox[type=checkbox] {
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 text-indent: 2.5px;
 display:none !important; 
}
input.checkbox[type=checkbox] + *:before {
 content: '\0020';
 display: inline-block;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 color: #0088EE;
 margin-right: 5px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}
input.checkbox[type=checkbox]:checked + *:before {
 content: '\2713';
 font-size: 1.0625em;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' id='mycheckbox'/>
<label for='mycheckbox'>Some Checkbox</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
    <label for="test1">Red</label>
 </p>
<style>
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: 2px;
  width: 17px; height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px; left: 4px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #09ad7e;
  transition: all .2s;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #bbb;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
  color: #999;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  color: #aaa;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}


label:hover:before {
  border: 1px solid #4778d9!important;
}

</style>
```